# Ubuntu 18.04 sound volume auto adjusting when headphones are plugged in

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, volume-control

the problem is that whenever I plug in headphones in my PC headphone jack (not Line out) the system is actively adjusting my sound volume according to some sound spikes and louder voices, like in sudden movie scenes or even if I turn up the volume above ~30% when listening to music. This is massively frustrating as I hate it very much and cannot disable it. If I plug headphones into Line Out jack, the problem does not appear, sound is being played as is. Is there a way to disable this feature? I could'nt find any info anywhere since I don't even know how it's called so I ended up here asking.

Looks like that there must have been implemented some sort of ear protection or something similar but I can't find any specific pulseaudio modules to disable this feature. It must be capping the maximum volume or trying to normalize it to cancel out more sudden sound hops.

Additional info:

This problem appeared a few weeks ago or maybe a month ago, I guess with some new updates. Before that there was no such thing at all.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version, motherboard is MSI X570-A PRO which has Realtek HD Audio chip. Currently I am not using that Headphone jack in Ubuntu because of that feature ruining all the sound expirience. To assure that this is Ubuntu only problem I've tested it on Windows 10 and there is no such volume regulation over headphones.

I would be very thankful for any information and possible solutions.